# apk not updating changes when building with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to test an ionic app on the emulator and on an android phone but neither works. Even though I can install and execute the application it is always an Ionic Blank Starter. The changes made can be seen on the browser when using serve but the apk generated on build doesn´t change.

Comment: which version of cordova you are using?

Comment: What command do you use to build the apk?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem quite often. 
My solution: delete the old APK before generating the new one.

I don't know why but it seems that there is a caching somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic serve shows changes in the code dinamically, but you have to `ionic build` and `ionic run` to make the changes affect the apk

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall app then run "ionic cordova emulate android" again.

Do it with every change. This is the fastest way for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the www folder and removing android platform and adding it again solved the problem for me :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```